# Why can't apply edge loop on the selected face?

Tags: modeling, edges, extrude, loop

Very beginner in Blender. I drew this simple box, and now I want to apply an loop cut to the select face in order to extrude part of my face,.

When I try to insert the loop cut, Blender add loop only to the edge side and not all around.

Why us this happening?

I'm expecting loop cut circle around my box.

[image: pic]

Comment: It looks like the center face may be an n-gon due to that edge down the middle of the "top" face (I cant see if it connects). Try dissolving that edge.

Comment: ... non-completing Ctrl-R loops are a useful diagnostic tool. After trying CB's suggestion, have a look for duplicate faces/vertices, too. Maybe you had 2 shots at that  extrusion, and didn't completely undo the first?